# Why does Visual Studio show important task list items twice, once with the exclamation mark and once without?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

If I define a high-priority task list token in Visual Studio, like this:

[image]

and I use it in code like this:

[image]

it shows up twice in the task list, once with an exclamation mark and once without:

[image]

All high priority items appear at the top of the list, which is good.  But then they all appear again in their relative sort locations intermixed with regular priority items below the high priority items.

What is the intended purpose of this behavior?

Before you down vote or vote to close this as "not useful", please consider what happens when you heavily use task items and have dozens of high-priority items scattered among regular priority items with no clear differentiation.  In my example, I have the word "Important" in the token so it's clear, but it obviously doesn't have to be that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your TODO << IMPORTANT >> matches both the regularly defined TODO, as well as your TODO << IMPORTANT >> tag. If you want to see three, add a TODO << IMPORTANT >> MORE and set your comment up to `// TODO << IMPORTANT >> MORE`. Now you'll have three tasks, and all could have different priorities.

I think you're just going to need to define tokens that don't conflict if you want your desired behavior.

Comment: Ahh, yes of course.  I guess they could probably have checked for a longer token before considering the shorter one, but I can see how that's not that "high a priority" for them!